# String Concatenation Error

Tags: ruby, operators, syntax-error

I ran into a syntax error.  I accept that it's a syntax error, but I'm somewhat curious as to *why* it's a syntax error.

This works exactly as you'd expect it to:

```
(0..9).each { |n| puts n.to_s + "^2 = " + (n**2).to_s }
```

This throws an error:

```
(0..9).each { |n| puts n.to_s +"^2 = "+ (n**2).to_s }
```

The error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method '+@' for "^2 = ":String
```

Oddly, I can move the second plus sign wherever and Ruby seems to have no problem with it, but if that first one happens to touch the double quote, I get a syntax error.

Why exactly does this happen?

Comment: It seems like when you do `.to_s +"` it's thinking that the `+"` is a parameter to to_s. Try doing `.to_s() +"` and it works fine. Not an answer, but a clue :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`n.to_s +"^2 = "` is parsed as `n.to_s(+"^2 = ")`, which is syntactically valid and means "perform the unary plus operations on the string `^2 =` and then pass the result as an argument to `to_s`". However since strings don't have a unary plus operation (represented by the method `+@`), you get a `NoMethodError` (*not* a syntax error).

The reason that it's parsed this way and not as `n.to_s() + "^2 = "` is that if it were parsed this way then `puts +5` or `puts -x` would also have to be parsed as `puts() + 5` and `puts() - x` rather than `puts(+5)` and `puts(-x)` - and in that example it's rather clear that the latter is what was intended.

Comment: Nicely done. It didn't occur to me that to_s was taking all of that in as an argument.