# String concatenation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, concatenation

I'm wondering why this is so: Ruby concatenates two strings if there is a space between the plus and the next string. But if there is no space, does it apply some unary operator?

```
params['controller'].to_s + '/'
# => "posts/"

params['controller'].to_s +'/'
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "/":String
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Concatenation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861693/string-concatenation-error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parser is interpreting `+'/'` as the first parameter to the `to_s` method call. It is treating these two statements as equivalent:

```
> params['controller'].to_s +'/'
# NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "/":String

> params['controller'].to_s(+'/')
# NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "/":String
```

If you explicitly include the parenthesis at the end of the `to_s` method call the problem goes away:

```
> params['controller'].to_s() +'/'
=> "posts/"
```

Comment: no **undefined method `+@' for "/":String** not for your explanations.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to concatenate a string, the safest way is to write `"#{params[:controller].to_s} /"` ruby's string escaping is safer and better in many cases

Comment: `safer` is the kicker!

Answer (score 4):

Look closely the error:

```
p "hi".to_s +'/'
p "hi".to_s -'2'

#=> in `<main>': undefined method `+@' for "/":String (NoMethodError)
```

This is because `unary operator` `+`,`-` etc is defined only `Numeric` class objects. It will be clear if you look at the code below:

```
p "hi".to_s +2
#=>in `to_s': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Now the above error is exactly right for `to_s`. As `to_s` doesn't take any argument when it is called.

Correct version is:

```
p "hi".to_s + '2' #=> "hi2"
```