# what's -@ and +@ causes NoMethodError for String

Tags: ruby

**POSSIBLE DUPLICATE** [String concatenation in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864068/string-concatenation-in-rails-3)

*I use Ruby 2.0.0-p247.*

`+@` and `-@` will cause `NoMethodError` when you are not careful with spaces.

If you put a string stick with `+` and `-`, you will see `NoMethodError`

```
pry> +""
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "\n":String

pry> -""
NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for "\n":String
```

more error examples:

1.

```
pry> x + "\n"
NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
pry> x +"\n"
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "\n":String
```

2.

```
pry> def x

pry> def x; 1; end

pry> x +"\n"
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "\n":String
```

3.

```
pry> class X
pry>   def y
pry>     1
pry>   end
pry> end
=> nil
pry> x = X.new
=> #<X:0x00000100ce48b0>
pry> x.y +"\n"
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for "\n":String
```

I found there is something called [`TkVariable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkVariable.html) But this has nothing to do with TkVariable.

This is about `+` precedence. Could someone explain the `+` when used with String?

Thanks!

Comment: You can search this site for funky symbols - e.g. try searching for [ruby] "+@".

Comment: Yes! But I want to know these two in String. In other situation it's an unary operator.

Comment: I don't understand that. Ruby's telling you they don't exist for string.

Comment: If you want to concat an "\n" for `x`: `x + "\n"` but you made a mistake and type `x +"\n"`, then this error will occur.

Comment: @juanitofatas I just tried that in IRB; I didn't get an error. If you have `x` before the plus sign it's interpreted as the `+` method on `x`, not the unary `+` method on `"\n"`.

Comment: every errors are expected..What made you confused?

Comment: please see my edited question, I have added more cases that will cause this error.

Comment: @Babai I found what makes me confused, please see this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864068/string-concatenation-in-rails-3

Comment: @Babai I am confused why `+` not combined with left-side first.

Answer (score 5):

> what are +@ and -@ in Ruby?

These are `unary plus` and `unary minus`.But these are not defined for `String` objects,but defined for `Fixnum` objects.

See the below for the same:

```
2.respond_to?(:+@)
# => true
2.respond_to?(:-@)
# => true

"".respond_to?(:+@)
# => false
"".respond_to?(:-@)
# => false
```

> I am confused why + not combined with left-side first.

This because unary operator has [`higher precedence`](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence) than binary operator.

```
class X
   def y
     "1"
   end
end
x = X.new
x.y +"b" # undefined method `+@' for "b":String (NoMethodError) <~~ A
x.y + "b" # => "1b" <~~ B
```

In case A error happened,as `String#+@` not defined,but in case B, `String#+` defined.Moreover `x.y +"b"` here `+` is an unary operator,where as in `x.y + "b"` ;  `+`  is a binary operator.